# Update a record in custom module

Tags: 7

I've read several custom module tutorials but none seem to show how to edit a record. My module does not use node but has a custom table. So, I think I ought to be able to drupal_get_form and populate the #value with the fields. But to set up the menu to get the parameter in the URL and my page callback is not working.

Looking around I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029519/drupal-pass-argument-to-page) and modeled the below after it but I get a default page instead of my expected form.

```
$items['redashboard/project/%/edit'] = array(
  'title' => (t('Edit project')),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('re_dashboard_edit_project_form', 2),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
);

function re_dashboard_edit_project_form($form, $form_state, $projectid) {
  $project = pull_project($projectid);
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Research Project Name/Question'),
    '#value' => $project->projectName,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Create',
  );
  return $form;
}

function pull_project($projectid) {
  $query = db_select('Projects', 'p');
  $query->fields('p', array('ProjectID', 'residentID', 'projectName', 'projectMentor', 'projectStatus', 'citation', 'lastUpdated'));
  $query->condition('ProjectID', $projectid);
  $result = $query->execute();
  return $result->fetch();
}
```

So, how should I set up a page to edit this record if not this way? Or to the point how should I set up the menu so that this callback gets rendered? thx, sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$items['redashboard/project/%/edit']` declaration needs to be made inside of `re_dashboard_menu()`, and there needs to be a `re_dashboard_edit_project_form_submit()` function to pipe `$form_state['values']` into `db_update()`.

Other than that, it looks like it will get the job done.  You could use `db_query()` instead of `db_select()`, since it's faster, and the query conditions are static.  Also, make sure you have a way to handle `db_select()` not returning any results, since `fetch()` will return `FALSE` in that case.

Comment: Yes, the menu() and re_dashboard_edit_project_form_submit() was left off for clarity. But you are right and will check for empty in my submit handler. But I'm still not getting to this page, even after drush cc all

Comment: Another day, a fresh restart seems to have shaken its cobwebs. Thanks for validating the page args.